# In VS code I tried solving a problem using python,selenium, behave but I'm not getting the correct output. Can you tell me where the problem is?

Tags: python-behave

my folders are

> features/features_files_folder
>
> features/steps

In features_files_folder

> omniwyse.feature

code:

Feature: Omniwyse

```
@tagcurrent
Scenario Outline: COMPANY 
    Given I load the website "https://www.omniwyse.com"
    When I click "About Us" page
    Then verify about header element "About Us"
```

**init**.py

In steps folder

step_def_web_element_handling.py

```
from behave import given, when, then

from step_impl_web_element_handling import webapp

@given(u'I load the website "{url}"')
def step_impl(context,url):
    webapp.load_website(url)

@when(u'I click "About Us" page')
def step_impl_goto_page(context):
    webapp.goto_page()


@then(u'verify about header element "{component}"')
def step_impl_verify_component(context, component):
    webapp.verify_component_exists(component)
```

step_impl_web_element_handling.py

```
from selenium import webdriver

driverpath = "/Users/giris/Downloads/chromedriver"


class WebApp:

    def __init__(self):
        pass
        # self.driver.get("https://omniwyse.com/")

    def load_website(self, url):
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = driverpath)
        driver.get(url)

    def goto_page(self):
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = driverpath)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[normalize-space()='About Us']").click()

    def verify_component_exists(self, component):
        # Simple implementation
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = driverpath)
        assert component in driver.find_element_by_xpath("//h1[contains(text(),'About Us')]"), \
            "Component {} not found on page".format(component)


webapp = WebApp()
```

my errors for step_def_web_element_handling

```
{
    "resource": "/c:/Users/giris/OneDrive/Documents/pythonassignment/omni/features/steps/step_def_web_element_handling.py",
    "owner": "python",
    "code": "no-name-in-module",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "No name 'then' in module 'behave'",
    "source": "pylint",
    "startLineNumber": 4,
    "startColumn": 1,
    "endLineNumber": 4,
    "endColumn": 1
}
```

same for given, when

output when run using behave command

> Using default path "./features" Trying base directory:
> C:\Users\giris\OneDrive\Documents\pythonassignment\omni\features
> Feature: Omniwyse # features/feature_files_folder/omniwyse.feature:1
>
> 1 feature passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped 0 scenarios passed, 0 failed, 0
> skipped 0 steps passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped, 0 undefined Took 0m0.000s

Desired output:

> Using default path "./features" Trying base directory:
> C:\Users\giris\OneDrive\Documents\pythonassignment\omni\features
> Feature: Omniwyse # features/feature_files_folder/omniwyse.feature:1
>
> 1 feature passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped 1 scenario passed, 0 failed, 0
> skipped 3 steps passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped, 0 undefined Took 0m0.000s

Answer (score 0):

In omniwyse.feature

Replace scenario outline with scenario